# Print array at given position

Tags: java, arrays, printing

I am trying to print out two arrays at given position.

The program has two parts. One where the user is asked to enter a string(student name) and an int (student grade) at the end the user is asked to search for the name entered and to print out the student name and the grade

So far I cant't print any.

This is my code for populating the arrays...

```
System.out.println("Please Enter The Number Of Students In The Class!!");     
    int numberOfStudents = input.nextInt();
    String []studentNames = new String[numberOfStudents];                                         
    int [] StudentGrades = new int[numberOfStudents];
    int i;
    for (i =0; i<numberOfStudents; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter Student Name!");                                  
        studentNames[i]= input.next();
        System.out.println("_________________");                                    
        System.out.println("Enter Student Grade");
        StudentGrades[i] = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("_________________");
    }
```

... and this for searching the name:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nameInput = input.next();
    int cheak;
    cheak = 0;

    for ( String student : studentNames)

        {
            if (nameInput.equals(student))
            {
                cheak++;
            }
        }
    if (cheak !=0)
    {
        System.out.println("Name Found ");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Name Not Found");
    }
```

Now I want to print the student name that is entered in the search with the corresponding grade.

How do I accomplish that?

Comment: I fixed the grammar of your question and improved the layout and added the question that you probably wanted to ask. As it looks like java code I added that tag. You might revisit [ask] and [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to further [edit] your question into shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to just keep a record of the index of target name in the studentNames array.
You can modify the loop in the following way to get the index in the cheak variable -

```
cheak = 0;
for ( String student : studentNames)
    {  
        if (nameInput.equals(student))
        {
            break;
        }
        cheak++;
    }
if (cheak != numberOfStudents)
{
    System.out.println("Name Found. Name = " + studentNames[cheak] + " Grade = " + StudentGrades[cheak]);
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Name Not Found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
for ( String student : studentNames) {
        if (nameInput.equals(student)) {//if the student is found, stop the loop
            break;
        }
        cheak++;
    }
if (cheak != studentNames.length){
    System.out.println("Name Found ");
    System.out.println("The name is: " + studentNames[cheak]);
    System.out.println("Grade is: " + studentGrades[cheak]);
} else {
    System.out.println("Name Not Found");       
}
```